# What's stopping this from being "universal"?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I place this script on another Hingejoint, interacting with each one affects them all.

How can I make it so it only affects the Hingejoint I'm interacting with?

I'm using RayCast to determine what I hit first, but I don't want to write an if statement for each Hingejoint collider.

```c#
public class Hingetest : MonoBehaviour
{

    public HingeJoint Door;
    public float rotatedoor = 0.0f;
    public static bool hasbeenHit = false; 

    void Update()
    {

        if (hasbeenHit == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
                rotatedoor = rotatedoor + h;
            }

        }
        rotatedoor = (rotatedoor < 0f) ? 0f : (rotatedoor > 120f) ? 120f : rotatedoor;
        JointSpring doorSpring = Door.spring;
        doorSpring.targetPosition = rotatedoor;
        Door.spring = doorSpring;
    }

}
```

Raycast script.

```c#
public class RaycastInteraction : MonoBehaviour {

    public float distanceToSee;
    RaycastHit whatIHit;

    public GameObject object1;
    public GameObject object2;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        int layerMask = 1 << 8;
        layerMask = ~layerMask;

        if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward, out whatIHit, distanceToSee, layerMask))
        {
            if (whatIHit.collider.gameObject == object1)
            {
                Debug.Log("hithasbeenmade");
                Hingetest.hasbeenHit = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# static - What does the definition on MSDN mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079233/c-sharp-static-what-does-the-definition-on-msdn-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasbeenHit` is a `static` variable and therefore "shared" among all components of your type `Hingetest`. So when you set it to `true` you set this value for all `Hingetest` components!

---

Make it a normal `public` variable

```
public bool hasbeenHit = false;
```

and set it like

```
whatIHit.gameObject.GetComponent<Hingetest>().hasbeenHit = true;
```

than you should be fine.

---

You probably should take a step back and get some more c#-basics before directly trying to change things in Unity. E.g. [c# static](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-static)

Comment: Thanks!! Works perfectly.